# charts.js fixed y label to 8 decimals

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How I can modify Y that I have number like `0.00000034`, because I have `3.4e-7`?

Here is my pice of code:

```
var speedData = {
    labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    datasets: [{
        label: "BTC-DOGE",
        data: [0.00000008, 0.00000042],
        lineTension: 0,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'orange',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderDash: [5, 5],
        pointBorderColor: 'orange',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,150,0,0.5)',
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
        pointHitRadius: 30,
        pointBorderWidth: 2,
        pointStyle: 'rectRounded'
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work.

```
var speedData = {
labels: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
 datasets: [{
label: "BTC-DOGE",
data: [0.00000008,0.00000042],
lineTension: 0,
fill: false,
borderColor: 'orange',
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
borderDash: [5,5],
pointBorderColor: 'orange',
pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,150,0,0.5)',
pointRadius: 5,
pointHoverRadius: 10,
pointHitRadius: 30,
pointBorderWidth: 2,
pointStyle: 'rectRounded'
 }]
};
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: speedData
});
```

Comment: Not,you just run this code,i still have Y values like 3.5e-7 but i need to have 0.00000034.